# Azure Pipelines - Use System.AccessToken within a Python Script

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am working on a pipeline where the majority of code is within a python script that I call in the pipeline. In the script I would like to use the predefined variable System.AccessToken to make a call to the DevOps API that sets the status of a pull request.

However, when I try to get the token using `os.environ['System.AccessToken']` I get a key error.

Oddly though, it seems that System.AccessToken is set, because in the yaml file for the pipeline I am able to access the API like:

```
curl -u ":$(System.AccessToken)" URL
```

and get back a valid response. Is there something additional I need to do in Python to access this variable?

Comment: Can you try ```os.environ['SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN']```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing the page that Mani posted I found the answer. For most variables, something like System.AccessToken would have a corresponding SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN.

However, with a secret variable this is not the case. I was able to make it accessible to my python script by adding:

```
env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

to where the Python script is called in the pipeline's yaml file.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables for more details.

Comment: Hi Sirch, how are you using the access token? I was trying to find a way to use it with DefaultAzureCredential or at least in a similar way, but documentation is really lacking when it comes to Python in Azure Pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

with this documentation it can work: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate?tabs=cmd

Just change the language to "read in english"

There must be a vault and a present Secret aka SAS Token.
And I have to say your code above is curl not python.

---

```
import os
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

# Acquire the resource URL
vault_url = os.environ["KEY_VAULT_URL"]

# Acquire a credential object
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

# Acquire a client object
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=credential)

# Attempt to perform an operation
retrieved_secret = secret_client.get_secret("secret-name-01")
```

with this save change the fields to your vault and secret name the file as test.py and run it.

---

If you need the token outside, each Environment have it own namespace.
So adding it in local context with export ... or
follow the Unix policy, "everything is a file" write it to file.
Good practise here is to use ansible-vault or something similar.
store it encrypted, use it if you need it.

read it from file.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that the last code snippet is not in Python, I just was showing an example of what worked. I found another solution, but thank you for showing me this, it seems like it could useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `os.environ['SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN']` . As mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables the **case/format of the environment variables** is different

Comment: This doesn't work but did lead me to the answer, thank you. For secret variables there is no corresponding environment variable, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables